# Very slow R loop

Tags: r, performance, loops, if-statement

I am trying to populate a column as follows:

At `t-1`: `if NAV(t-1) - HWM(t-1) >0`

then at `t`: `HWM(t) = NAV(t)`   otherwise: `HWM(t) = HWM(t-1)`

My R skills are quite elementary and the following loop, though it works, is excruciatingly slow (150,000 observations)

```
for (i in 1:length(E$HWM)) {
  print(i)
  HWM[E$t>2][i] <- ifelse( NAV_lag1[E$t>2][i] - HWM_lag1[E$t>2][i] > 0 ,
                           NAV_lag1[E$t>2][i] ,
                           HWM_lag1[t>2[i] )
  HWM_lag1[i] <-lag(HWM,1)[i]
}
```

Any suggestions to make my process more efficient?

Thank you very much.

Here is what I have:

```
zz <- "t   NAV          HWM         NAV_lag1    HWM_lag1
1          1000         NA          NA          NA 
2          1200         1000        1000        NA 
3          1400         NA          1200        NA 
4          1200         NA          1400        NA 
5          1100         NA          1200        NA 
5          1000         NA          1100        NA "
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
zz <- "t   NAV          HWM         NAV_lag1   HWM_lag1
1          1000         NA          NA         NA 
2          1200         1000        1000       1000 
3          1400         1200        1200       1000 
4          1200         1400        1400       1200
5          1100         1400        1200       1400
5          1000         1400        1100       1400"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: isn't `cummax(Data$NAV_lag1)` what you want? and `c(NA, head(cummax(Data$NAV), -1))`.. oh this doesn't work for ties in the NAV_lag1 example..

Comment: your first zz doesn't work.

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what you want from this question (a reproducible example would help), but this sounds like a perfect thing for the `data.table` package

Comment: I fixed the first zz. Does it make sense now? I need to populate HWM(t) with either HWM(t-1) or NAV(t-1), depending on the outcome of the condition NAV(t-1)-HMW(t-1)>0.